# VSTO Visio Add-In SolutionXmlElement error

Tags: c#, xml, vsto, visio

I am developing a VSTO add-in for Visio, and need to save document properties using Document.SolutionXmlElement property. The following code demonstrates the handler to serialize the XML for an object prior to save. Based upon reading I am wrapping the C# class instance in a SolutionXml wrapper with a Name attribute set to the element name of the exclosed serialized class instance:

```
        private void Document_Saved(Visio.Document document)
        {
        IDictionary<string, ModelGenMVCModel> documentModel = GetRibbon().documentModel;
        if (documentModel.TryGetValue(document.Name, out ModelGenMVCModel modelGenMVCModel))
        {
            try
            {
                string serializedModel = new SolutionXml(modelGenMVCModel,ModelGenVisioAddIn.Properties.Resources.SolutionXmlElementName).Serialize();
                LOGGER.Debug(String.Format("Saving model gen properties:\n{0}", serializedModel));
                document.SolutionXMLElement[ModelGenVisioAddIn.Properties.Resources.SolutionXmlElementName] = serializedModel;
            } catch ( Exception e)
            {
                LOGGER.Error(String.Format("Serialization error {0}\n{1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace));
            }
        }
    }
```

The serializzed XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SolutionXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Name="ModelGenMVCModel">
    <ModelGenMVCModel>
        <Author>Andrew Tyson</Author>
        <UniqueID>Object_ID</UniqueID>
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <Description>Note</Description>
        <LineColor/>
        <FillColor/>
        <SearchMatchLineColor/>
        <SearchMatchFillColor/>
        <SearchMatchFontColor/>
        <SearchNoMatchLineColor/>
        <SearchNoMatchFillColor/>
        <LineWidth>1.5</LineWidth>
        <PopupHeight>250</PopupHeight>
        <PopupWidth>750</PopupWidth>
        <InitialZoom>2</InitialZoom>
        <MinZoom>0.05</MinZoom>
        <MaxZoom>2</MaxZoom>
        <ZoomSteps>0.05</ZoomSteps>
        <EnablePan>true</EnablePan>
        <EnableSearch>true</EnableSearch>
        <DragPan>true</DragPan>
        <MouseWheelZoom>true</MouseWheelZoom>
        <DoubleClickZoom>true</DoubleClickZoom>
        <PanDuration>300</PanDuration>
        <PanAmount>100</PanAmount>
        <OpenInBrowser>true</OpenInBrowser>
        <SaveToLocation/>
    </ModelGenMVCModel>
</SolutionXml>
```

However I am getting an "Invalid Parameter" exception thrown. Any assistance would be gratefully received.

Thanks and regards
Andrew

Comment: You need two classes in c# 1) SolutionXml 2) ModelGenMVCModel.  The SolutionXml class must have a property ModelGenMVCModel.  The model and the classes must match.  The other solution is to read the tag SolutionXml before passing the object to the deserializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a code sample here that demonstrates managing the SolutionXmlElement. You can check it out, if it works for you. It defines a simple class to save/load settings:

https://unmanagedvisio.com/using-solutionxml-with-c/

I belive, the problem might be, you actually need to put XML there, and not a serialized string. But without looking at the full example hard to tell.